# Libboost :: resolver received SIGABRT

Tags: c++11, networking, boost-asio

I found the following code to get the local IP addresses using libboost. I am using libboost-1.65.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

std::string getHostIP ()
{
    using boost::asio::ip::tcp;    

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    std::cout << boost::asio::ip::host_name() << std::endl;
    tcp::resolver::query query(boost::asio::ip::host_name(), "");
    tcp::resolver::iterator iter = resolver.resolve(query);
    tcp::resolver::iterator end; // End marker.
    while (iter != end)
    {
         tcp::endpoint ep = *iter++;
         std::cout << ep << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    getHostIP();
}
```

I am currently getting an output of

```
daniel-XVirtualBox
127.0.1.1:0
free(): invalid size
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The hostname is correct, and the IP address of the localhost. I know that there are multiple interfaces on the computer and that query can return any number of them, but I do not see the two other interfaces connected to the computer. I will add the output of *ifconfig* also.

However, my question is concerning the "free(): invalid size" bit. 
GDB says this in addition:

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
51  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.

***Backtrace***
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#1  0x00007ffff705a801 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007ffff70a3897 in __libc_message (action=action@entry=do_abort, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff71d0b9a "%s\n")
    at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:181
#3  0x00007ffff70aa90a in malloc_printerr (str=str@entry=0x7ffff71ceda0 "free(): invalid size") at malloc.c:5350
#4  0x00007ffff70b1e2c in _int_free (have_lock=0, p=0x7ffff7de5990 <_dl_init+864>, av=0x7ffff7405c40 <main_arena>)
    at malloc.c:4161
#5  __GI___libc_free (mem=0x7ffff7de59a0 <_dl_fini>) at malloc.c:3124
#6  0x0000555555559111 in main () at boost_gethostname.cpp:22
```

Is there a clean-up procedure for boost::asio::io_service that I am missing? Should the resolver be stopped? And also, why do I not see all the interfaces on the computer?

Thanks!

```
ifconfig: 
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::ecd6:f288:3b03:d8cf  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:37:63:98  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 114124  bytes 111705475 (111.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 42644  bytes 3732986 (3.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.10.11.221  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.10.11.255
        inet6 fe80::3aa2:ecbd:5702:2ab4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:a6:44:ce  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 194194  bytes 24826176 (24.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 7354  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1189  bytes 127853 (127.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 912  bytes 76283 (76.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 912  bytes 76283 (76.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the abortion. Can you show how you compiled the program? Side note: You don't return any `std::string`.

Comment: It happens that I am using gcc 4.9.4, that's why I couldn't reproduce your problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have triggered a nasty case of undefined behavior (UD), which ultimately lead to a `SIGABRT` in your program. In [9.6.3 [stmt.return]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/stmt.return#2):

> Flowing off the end of a constructor, a destructor, or a function with a cv void return type is equivalent to a return with no operand.
>   Otherwise, flowing off the end of a function other than main results in undefined behavior.

Technically, just about *anything* can happen with your code after your function returns. In most cases, nothing happens, everybody will be happy and therefore people mostly ignore warnings like `no return statement in function returning non-void`.

Now here you see why this can be a *very* bad thing. If you set the return type to `void` instead of `std::string` or if you *do* return some string, the program doesn't crash anymore.

While gcc-generated code seems to produce a [segfault](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LZGz4fr5xoDOX45B) or an [abort](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pkkuOp8PRVi0XFo0) (depending on the version), clang-generated code will issue an [illegal instruction](https://wandbox.org/permlink/628409auDGTNuetP). Both compilers do fine if you change the return type. For even more confusion, take gcc 4.9.x; here your code [just works fine](https://wandbox.org/permlink/TNOMoPDHM6qTuR8Q), despite UB.

This piece of code is a true sweetie pie of *undefined* behavior that can really mess up your application.

Comment: This is an excellent answer! Thank you very much for your excellent explanation, I have learned something today :) I have changed the signature to void and it works correctly now.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @andreee answer, **always** compile your code with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` to detect such nasty bugs at compile time. There is no excuse for not using these flags.

In my makefiles I usually use bash expansion `-W{all,extra,error}`.